# Imprimir vector de forma horizontal

Tags: java

Tengo un error con mi codigo y es que cuando cierro el ciclo for y agrego el if en la ultima parte me imprime el vector de forma vertical y lo que busco es que se imprima de forma horizontal les agradeceria mucho si me pueden orientar ;).

```
    package com.company;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int [] vector = new int[100];//iniciamos el vector y su tamaño.
        for (int i = 1; i < vector.length; i++)//Creamos un ciclo for para su llenada.
        {
            vector[i] = (int)(Math.random()*50);//El llenado solo sera hasta el numero 50.
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < vector.length; i++)//Creamos un ciclo for para imprimir los numeros guardados.
        {
            System.out.print(vector[i] + " ");
            System.out.println("");
            if(i==42)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu error se encuentra en esta línea:

```
System.out.println("");
```

println se encarga de imprimir código, pero hace también un cambio de línea, si quieres que se imprima horizontal, reemplazalo por print.

```
System.out.print(" ");
```

añado el espacio para que separe tus valores.

Comment: jaja si si me di cuenta 3sg cuando termine de publicarlo Gracias.